# How to collapse multiple rows of different size to one in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame, with:
'''

```
1st column = subject_id,
2nd column = voxel_type (categorical; T, P, or C),
3rd to 10th columns = floats
```

'''
Since I have multiple rows for each subject, I want to collapse them all into one row, to leave only one row per subject.
My first thought was to use groupby, as other questions on SO suggest. However, I have different row counts per subject... how do I approach this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please include [`Minimal, Reproducible Example`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goo day,

It's a bit hard to see what you want, but here is something to that direction. What you most likely are looking for is **pivot** or **pivot_table**. Here is an example where I did a with my best guess:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Lets generate some dummy data:

```
begin = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3], 
                      'tp': ['t','p','c']*3, 
                     'foo': [np.random.random()+1 for x  in range(9) ], 
                     'bar': [np.random.random()+2 for x  in range(9) ]  
                    })
```

Assumption: tp is not uniform and single id might have multiple tp-entries. Then we just pivot the table and list the columns which we want to have:

```
pd.pivot_table(begin, values=['foo', 'bar'], columns=['id', 'tp'])
```

if assumption prior is wrong, you can just do:

```
pd.pivot_table(begin, values=['tp,'foo', 'bar'], columns='id')
```

For more see [documentation on Pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, that got me on the right track!